# Error al imprimir caracteres especiales en winUI 3 con XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

He creado un proyecto en winUI 3 y creé una etiqueta texBlock.

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid"> 
    <TextBlock Text="Fecha mañana">
</TextBlock> </Grid>
```

cuando corro la apliación no muestra el caracter 'ñ'

sin embargo, cuando lo asigno con codigo en C#

```
'TextBlock tx = new TextBlock(); tx.Text = "mañana"; myGrid.Children.Add(tx);'
```

si me muestra correctamente.

saben a que se debe?

Comment: Eso se debe a que probablemente el xaml carga antes que la cultura de la máquina cargándola por la de por defecto la Cultura.Invariant. I digo probablemente, ya que no uso winUI3, pero se puede replicar en otros como framework al cambiar la cultura. La otra opcion es usar los caracteres especiales en formato unicode asi funcionan independientemente

Comment: Encontré una solución y es abrir el archivo xaml con vscode, cuando lo abro sale con un carácter ? lo modifico y lo guardo y vuelvo a visual studio y ya se pudo, parece que es como se guarda el archivo xaml, alguien sabría como configurar eso para no tener que hacer estos pasos.